# laravel 5 load model on every controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning laravel coming from a codeigniter background. I have an object I need to get from a model to be used in the navigation bar. The call I'm making is this.

```
$users = \App\Models\User::all();
```

I know I can do this on every controller

```
public function index()
{       
    $users = \App\Models\User::all();

    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
}
```

But I'm trying to get in good habits. What is the best practice for retrieving this data on every page in laravel 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `view` helper function to share data with every view:
`view()->share('data', [1, 2, 3]);`

You can do that in the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`.
For more information look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views).